# BCP Import From Snapshot Replication For Recovery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, bcp

To start with, I used the following link as my base to start: [Older post on SQL Server Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31390e12-1139-418b-bba8-24aac1a30c2b/how-to-restore-table-data-from-a-bcp-snapshot-file?forum=sqlreplication)

Target server is SQL Server 2016, which is the Distributor and Subscriber.  Source is SQL Server 2014.  Replication works fine.  This is about manually loading a table.

I am attempting to load the data from just one table of the Snapshot Replication source for a particular day.  My command looks like this:

```
MASTER.DBO.xp_cmdshell
  'bcp "MyDatabase.dbo.Invoices"
        in "\\UNCPath\SQLBKUP\unc\ReplicationDir_JOBSGROUP\20170916041316\Invoices_5#1.bcp"
        -SServerName -T -E -n -b 10000'
```

The BCP errors with the following, where the 10 error messages appear to be related to the 10 DATETIME2 fields in my table:

> output
>   NULL
>   Starting copy...
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype
>   NULL
>   BCP copy in failed
>   NULL

Since this is a snapshot replication, I used the .SCH file to recreate the structure just as would be done when replication does the load.  No change.  I've tried using a Format file (.FMT), and changing the command to use that.  Errors the same way.

Is there somewhere that BCP logs errors that I'm missing?  I've tried using the -e and error file location, but it creates a 0 byte file.

Really hope someone has a lead that will help me out.  Ask for more detail as needed.  I've checked the things like version, @@LANGUAGE, date formats (as best I know how), and more that other posts mention.  Replication completes successfully on this server every night with this same data/bcp source on this same server.  I feel like I'm trying to find the 1 switch that Replication services use that make this work.

Edit:  Adding FMT and SCH file info

FMT File

```
13.0
25
1       SQLBIGINT           0       8       ""   1     InvoiceId                                      ""
2       SQLBIGINT           1       8       ""   2     JobId                                          ""
3       SQLDATETIME2        0       8       ""   3     CreatedDateTime                                    ""
4       SQLNCHAR            2       500     ""   4     ExternalId                                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLINT              0       4       ""   5     SourceTypeID                                   ""
6       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   6     Status                                             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             2       2000    ""   7     Summary                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   8     InvoiceNumber                                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9       SQLDATETIME2        1       8       ""   9     InvoicedOn                                         ""
10      SQLMONEY            0       8       ""   10    Tax                                                ""
11      SQLMONEY            0       8       ""   11    SubTotal                                           ""
12      SQLMONEY            0       8       ""   12    Total                                              ""
13      SQLMONEY            0       8       ""   13    Balance                                            ""
14      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   14    RoyaltyStatus                                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15      SQLDATETIME2        1       8       ""   15    RoyaltySendOn                                      ""
16      SQLCHAR             2       1000    ""   16    RoyaltyMemo                                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
17      SQLDATETIME2        1       8       ""   17    ModifiedDateTime                               ""
18      SQLDATETIME2        1       8       ""   18    BatchModifiedDateTime                              ""
19      SQLDATETIME2        0       8       ""   19    UpdatedDateTime                                    ""
20      SQLDATETIME2        1       8       ""   20    RoyaltyDate                                        ""
21      SQLDATETIME2        1       8       ""   21    DepositedOn                                        ""
22      SQLBIT              1       1       ""   22    IsDeleted                                          ""
23      SQLBIGINT           1       8       ""   23    AdjustmentInvoiceID                            ""
24      SQLDATETIME2        1       8       ""   24    ExternalCreatedDateTime                            ""
25      SQLDATETIME2        1       8       ""   25    ExternalUpdatedDateTime                            ""
```

SCH produced by Replication Snapshot Agent

```
drop Table [dbo].[Invoices]
go
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoices](
    [InvoiceId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [JobId] [bigint] NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ExternalId] [nvarchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT     NULL,
    [SourceTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Summary] [varchar](2000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [InvoiceNumber] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [InvoicedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Tax] [money] NOT NULL,
    [SubTotal] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Total] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Balance] [money] NOT NULL,
    [RoyaltyStatus] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [RoyaltySendOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [RoyaltyMemo] [varchar](1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ModifiedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [BatchModifiedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [UpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [RoyaltyDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DepositedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AdjustmentInvoiceID] [bigint] NULL,
    [ExternalCreatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ExternalUpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL
)

GO
```

Thanks in advance.

KD

Comment: You could try logging the replication agent activity and see if it shows the detail of the BCP call that's used during a snapshot apply.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312292/how-to-enable-replication-agents-for-logging-to-output-files-in-sql-se

Comment: Can you show us the format of the date/time field, i.e. an example of such a value in your import file? I'm betting it is not in a format that can be converted to a `DATETIME2` type.

Comment: I've added schema produced by the snapshot replicaiton and format file I produced to try it with -f instead of -n arguments to the original post.  The snapshot folder does have an FMT file by default.  I have also attempted to use the FMT file and BULK INSERT and the only thing different that it tells me is about field 9 (InvoicedOn).  Not saying this is how I should do it, but it at least confirmed the error being Date oriented.

Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 9 (InvoicedOn).